# Google UID changes on login with Rails and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

For some reason, after I create a user via Omniauth, I can't login to that user again, because Google returns a different UID.

Essentially I first login with Google. If the user doesn't exist, I create a user, and save the UID. On the next login, I look for the user via provider and uid, and if the user has already "registered" then those two attributes should be able find the user. For some reason, Google returns a different UID than from the first login.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]

  def self.from_omniauth auth
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth.provider, auth.uid) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth auth
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.avatar = auth.info.image
    end
  end
end
```

OmniAuth Callback Controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in Through Google!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      flash.alert = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have not faced such issue with google, but you can still handle it since the google's email is unique.

```
def self.from_omniauth auth
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth.provider, auth.uid) ||  User.find_by_provider_and_email(auth.provider, auth.info[:email]) ||  User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
end
```